# Chmod 777 all the cgi files getting uploaded

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, chmod, cgi

In my ubuntu i have configured cgi in /var/www/html/webcgi so when files uploaded on that webcgi its not get executed , it shows me internal server error so i need to chmod. As webcgi is chowned www-data and uploader. so i tried to chmod 777 with uploader when files get uploaded, i mean the uploader use php chmod() function to give permission but thats not execute.. but when i chmod it from termial and chown it as www-data it gets executed.. is there any way to chmod files when it get uploaded. i thought to make a cronjob but that's not a good way..

Thanks!

Comment: "chmod 777" has never been a correct solution to any question regarding permissions. Never. You either need a sticky bit (like /tmp/) or the "others" should be at least "5" but preferably even "0". Files you download from a website should never be set to execute. You should parse them through an executable.

Answer (score 1):

Use ACLs:

```
setfacl -dm "u:www-data:rwx" /path/to/dir
```

Now `www-data` has access to this directory, also files created by `www-data` will inherit its permissions.

based on how your web server has been configured you might want to do this using `www-data` group:

```
setfacl -dm "g:www-data:rwx" /path/to/dir
```